# Errno EACCESS in "path" permission denied on Ruby Compass

Tags: ruby, windows, compass-sass

I'm trying to run Compass to watch some files with Ruby, but when I run `compass watch --sass-dir sass --css-dir css -s compressed --images-dir img --javascripts-dir js` i got a error Errno EACCESS in "path" permission denied on Ruby Compass.

*ruby version is 1.3.3p545

The folder is local and I don't have any idea of what to do.

Any help will be appreciate.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, I just get my Ruby folder in "C:/" from another computer, and put it in the non-working-compass computer, them I set the Path variable on the computer settings and everything worked fine. Still not getting what I was doing wrong but compass is pulling and overwriting files now.